# Remove an image when mouse leaves a div

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a 3X3 box and currently I have it so that when you hover over any one of the squares the background turns blue and then when you hover out the box reverts back to empty.  I also have it so that when any of the boxes are clicked an image appears.  What I am trying to accomplish now is to make it so that when the box is clicked the image will appear and when that same box is clicked again the image will disappear and so on using Jquery.

Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('.divs').hover(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#0000EE");
                console.log('hover');

            }, function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "");
                console.log('hoverout');
            });

            $('.divs').click(function () {
                $(this).prepend("<img class='divimg' src=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/SMirC-cool.svg/320px-SMirC-cool.svg.png>");
                console.log('divclicked');
            });
        });
```

[image: what my page currently looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if there is an image there already

```
var $img = $("img", this);
if ($img.length > 0)
    $img.remove();
else
    $(this).prepend("<img class='divimg' src=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/SMirC-cool.svg/320px-SMirC-cool.svg.png>");
```

If you don't want to remove the image, you just toggle the visibility

```
var $img = $("img", this);
if ($img.length > 0) {
    $img.toggle();
} else {
    $(this).prepend("<img class='divimg' src=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/SMirC-cool.svg/320px-SMirC-cool.svg.png>");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried jQuery().hide() and jQuery().show()

Comment: or maybe .toggle() so that you don't have to keep track of which are shown and which are not.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use CSS `:hover` attribute.

```
.divs:hover {
    background-color: #0000ee;
}
```

Regarding click you can add images to your `div`s and use jQuery toggling.

*HTML:*

```
<div class="divs"><img src="..." alt=""></div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$('.divs').click(function () {
    $(this).children("img").toggle();
});
```

Comment: This is a learning experience for me, so that's why I didn't use CSS in this case, but it would have been much easier. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code in you click function

```
if($('img.divimg').length == 0){
  $('img.divimg').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).remove()
  });
}else{
  $(this).prepend("<img class='divimg' style='display:none;' src=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/SMirC-cool.svg/320px-SMirC-cool.svg.png>").fadeIn();
}
```

Another option is to make the remove action on the added image (when it is clicked).

```
var img = $('<img>')
            .attr('src', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/SMirC-cool.svg/320px-SMirC-cool.svg.png')
            .addClass('divimg')
            .css('display', 'none')
            .bind('click', function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
$(this).prepend(img);
```

Comment: .bind will be .on in jquery 1.7+